# no ngmodule metadata found for [object Module]

Tags: angular, ionic4

I was reworking my routes by changing them from lazy loaded from a string reference into lazy loaded from a call to `import`.

My problem is, every time I navigate to one of the pages, I'm getting the following error message: No NgModule metadata found for '[object Module]'.

```
consolelogs.js:49 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No NgModule metadata found for '[object Module]'.
Error: No NgModule metadata found for '[object Module]'.
    at NgModuleResolver.resolve (compiler.js:20665)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:19794)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:25582)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:25565)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:25527)
    at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:216)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.wrapIntoObservable.pipe.Object [as project] (router.js:5369)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:46)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:36)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at NgModuleResolver.resolve (compiler.js:20665)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:19794)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:25582)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:25565)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:25527)
    at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:216)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.wrapIntoObservable.pipe.Object [as project] (router.js:5369)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:46)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:36)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
    at zone.scheduleMicroTask (zone-evergreen.js:858)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:34182)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:469)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1603)
```

What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, I was using lazy-loading for my routes but failed to correctly import the module of the page I was loading. Notice the missing call to `then()`.

```js
{
  path: "references",
  children: [
    {
      path: "",
      loadChildren: () =>
        import(
          "app/applications/requirements/requirements-references/requirements-references.module"
        ).then(m => m.RequirementsReferencesPageModule)
    },
    {
      path: ":referenceId",
      loadChildren: () =>
        import(
          "app/applications/requirements/requirements-references-detail/requirements-references-detail.module"
        )
    }
  ]
}
```

I missed the `then` part of the import. Remember to follow the following pattern:

`import("path-to-your-module").then(m => m.NameOfModule)`